# Multiple clients, same IP different port: Error Authentication

Tags: netty

Based on the Echo sample,
I am testing from my development machine and it only allows me one single client.

It fails Authentication on the second socket with the following error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry!!! I posted too quickly without noticing one property:

I missed:

```
IsSharable => true;
```

That allows for multiple connections for the same handler. The error is part the confusion as it complained about Authentication